# Python chatbot using semantic-kernel

Tags: python, sql-server, chatbot, semantic-kernel

#Python chatbot using semantic-kernel

- `- This is the code of chatbot in python using semantic kernel which gives answer via chat-GPT , but I want to add skill in this like I want to integrate it with my SQL server ,and then I want to give questions from my database to it like for ex. (what is the age of person_name in table_name) and it should give answer of my question using my database.

```
import asyncio

import semantic_kernel as sk
import semantic_kernel.connectors.ai.open_ai as sk_oai

sk_prompt = """
ChatBot can have a conversation with you about any topic.
It can give explicit instructions or say 'I don't know'
when it doesn't know the answer.

{{$chat_history}}
User:\> {{$user_input}}
ChatBot:\>
"""

kernel = sk.Kernel()

//in this we give our api key and our org id from open ai
api_key, org_id = sk.openai_settings_from_dot_env()
kernel.add_text_completion_service(
"davinci-003", sk_oai.OpenAITextCompletion("text-davinci-003", api_key, org_id)
)

//in this according to tokens it will give more punctuations and by temperature it gives more creative answer as high value more creative answer
prompt_config = sk.PromptTemplateConfig.from_completion_parameters(
max_tokens=2000, temperature=0.7, top_p=0.4
)

prompt_template = sk.PromptTemplate(
sk_prompt, kernel.prompt_template_engine, prompt_config
)

//creating semantic function that runs 
function_config = sk.SemanticFunctionConfig(prompt_config, prompt_template)
chat_function = kernel.register_semantic_function("ChatBot", "Chat", function_config)


//code to continue chat
async def chat(context_vars: sk.ContextVariables) -\> bool:
try:
user_input = input("User:\> ")
context_vars\["user_input"\] = user_input
except KeyboardInterrupt:
print("\\n\\nExiting chat...")
return False
except EOFError:
print("\\n\\nExiting chat...")
return False

    if user_input == "exit":
        print("\n\nExiting chat...")
        return False
    
    answer = await kernel.run_async(chat_function, input_vars=context_vars)
    context_vars["chat_history"] += f"\nUser:> {user_input}\nChatBot:> {answer}\n"
    
    print(f"ChatBot:> {answer}")
    return True

async def main() -\> None:
context = sk.ContextVariables()
context\["chat_history"\] = ""

    chatting = True
    while chatting:
        chatting = await chat(context)

if __name__ == "__main__":
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: What is your question here? What does it have to do with SQL Server...?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.